# How to replace the string in this date format

Tags: php, string, date, replace

Actual Format 2015-12-16T00:00:00Z

i need like

Result Format: 2015-12-16 00:00:00

i tried this code
$cc=str_replace("T",'',2015-12-16T00:00:00Z);

Answer (score 1):

Using **str_replace**:

```
$cc = str_replace('Z', '', str_replace('T', ' ', '2015-12-16T00:00:00Z'));
```

OR

using **preg_replace**:

```
 $cc = preg_replace(array('/T/', '/Z/'), array(' ', ''), '2015-12-16T00:00:00Z');
```